# Use a custom domain instead of subdomain for a webapp that depends on the subdomain as a key

Tags: domains, dns, cname

I have a cloud application with subdomain per customer on Domain B.

- *customer1.B.com*
- *customer2.B.com*

Customer1 now wants to link to the application to use a subdomain of his own domain A. E.g. *app.A.com*

The cloud application depends on the subdomain (customer1), because it is using this as marker for loading the correct data. 
Is it possible in any way to "hide" the application behind another domain/subdomain (e.g. with CNAME)?

Comment: I changed the title because it sounds like you don't want redirects, you want to know how to implement a custom domain for this case.   A CNAME will point the custom domain to the correct server, but it wouldn't solve the problem of the subdomain being required for use as a marker.   With just using a CNAME, the subdomain information wouldn't be sent with the request.